# Soma retorna NAN mesmo convertendo o número em angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho uma estrutura de repetição que deve somar alguns valores:

A variável `qtdeEstoque` foi definida como `number` e a variavel `variacaoForm.value.variacoes.estoque_variacao` é um número, porém quando tento somar desta maneira em vez de incrementar o valor ele coloca na frente, por exemplo: número `10` e `5`, ele junta e fica `105`:

```
  for(let i=0;i<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;i++){
       this.qtdeEstoque+= this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].estoque_variacao
  }
  console.log(this.qtdeEstoque);
```

Tentei algumas outras maneiras utilizando `toInt()` e `Number()`:

```
  for(let i=0;i<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;i++){
    this.qtdeEstoque+= Number(this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].estoque_variacao)
  }
  console.log(this.qtdeEstoque);
```

Porém retorna `NAN`, como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Você possui um exemplo de dados para teste? Ex: 15.45

Comment: os valores são int, conforme especificado na publicação, se colocar 10 e 5 ele concatena e fica 105, e usando toInt() e Number() retorna NAN

Comment: Como que vc definiu essa propriedade qtdeEstoque?

Comment: pq ela tomou down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## App

```
this.qtdeEstoque = 0;  
for(let i=0;i<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;i++){
       this.qtdeEstoque+= this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].estoque_variacao
  }
  console.log(this.qtdeEstoque);
```

## dicas:

quando for adicionar o valor `public qtdeEstoque: number = 0` você pode se adiantar de uma vez só

Comment: Deu certo, precisava inicializar essa variavel com valor 0.

Comment: este :number e redundante se vc inicializar com 0 o typescript já determina o tipo pra number.